# Как установить лимит на количество элементов в множестве?

Tags: c++

Программа должна реализовать действия над множествами. Но почему-то список элементов множества не ограничен. Я не могу закончить множество. Как установить лимит на количество элементов в множестве?
(код не я писал)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

class Array
{
    int *mas, k;
    void Add(int);
    void Sub(int);
public:
    Array() :k(0), mas(new int(0)) {};
    Array(const Array &);
    ~Array() { delete[]mas; };
    void operator+=(int n) { Add(n); };
    void operator+=(Array &);
    void operator-=(int n) { Sub(n); };
    void operator-=(const Array &);
    Array operator*(const Array &)const;
    void operator*=(const Array &);
    friend bool operator==(Array &, Array &);
    friend bool operator<=(Array &, Array &);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &, const Array &);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &s, Array &);
    int HowMany() { return k; };
};

Array::Array(const Array &x) :k(x.k)
{
    mas = new int[k];
    for (int i = 0; i<k; i++)
        mas[i] = x.mas[i];
}

void Array::Add(int n)
{
    int *t, pos;
    for (pos = 0; pos<k && mas[pos]<n; pos++) {}
    if (mas[pos] != n)
    {
        t = new int[++k];
        for (int i = 0; i<k - 1; i++)
            t[i<pos ? i : i + 1] = mas[i];
        t[pos] = n;
        delete[]mas;
        mas = t;
    }
}

void Array::operator+=(Array &x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<x.k; i++)
        Add(x.mas[i]);
}

void Array::Sub(int n)
{
    if (k>0)
    {
        int *t, pos;
        for (pos = 0; pos<k && mas[pos]<n; pos++) {}
        if (mas[pos] == n)
        {
            t = new int[--k];
            for (int i = 0; i<k + 1; i++)
                if (i != pos) t[i<pos ? i : i - 1] = mas[i];
            delete[]mas;
            mas = t;
        }
    }
}

void Array::operator-=(const Array &x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<x.k; i++)
        return Sub(x.mas[i]);
}

Array Array::operator*(const Array &x)const
{
    Array t(*this), t2(*this);
    t -= x;
    for (int i = 0; i<t.k; ++i)
        t2.Sub(t.mas[i]);
    return t2;
}

void Array::operator*=(const Array &x)
{
    Array t(*this);
    t -= x;
    for (int i = 0; i<t.k; i++)
        Sub(t.mas[i]);
}

bool operator==(Array &x, Array &y)
{
    if (x.k != y.k) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i<x.k; i++)
        if (x.mas[i] != y.mas[i]) return false;
    return true;
}

bool operator<=(Array &x, Array &y)
{
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<x.k; i++)
        while (x.mas[i] != y.mas[i + s])
        {
            if (x.k + s>y.k) return false;
            s++;
        }
    return true;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, const Array &p)
{
    if (p.k != 0) {
        s << "(";
        for (int i = 0; i<p.k - 1; i++) {
            s << p.mas[i] << ",";
        }
        s << p.mas[p.k - 1];
    }
    return s << ")";
}
istream &operator>>(istream &s, Array &p)
{
    int tmp;
    char c;
    s >> c;

    while (c != ')')
    {
        s >> tmp >> c;
        p.Add(tmp);
    }
    return s;

}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    Array a, b, c;
    cout << " Введите множество А: " << "\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << a << "\n";
    a -= 9;
    cout << "После вычитания из множества элемента 9: " << a << "\n";
    cout << " Введите множество B: " << "\n";
    cin >> b;
    b += 7;
    cout << "После добавления в множествo элементa 7 : " << b << "\n";
    cout << " Пересечение множеств A и В: " << "\n";
    cout << a * b << "\n";
    cout << "Количество элементов в множестве В: " << b.HowMany() << "\n";
    if (a <= b)
        cout << "А - подмножество В \n";
    else {
        if (b <= a)
            cout << "B - подмножество A \n";
    }
    cout << " Объединение множеств А и B: " << "\n";
    c = a;
    a += b;
    cout << a << "\n";
    cout << " Разница множеств А и B: " << "\n";
    c -= b;
    cout << c << "\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `Array::Add` нужно подправить. Как именно - вам виднее.

Comment: Зачем вам лимит на количество елементов в контейнере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <size_t sz>
class Array
{    
    //...
    // sz будет ограничителем        
};
```

или  если нужен не шаблонный класс, 
 укажите ограничитель в аргументе  конструктора и храните его в классе.

```
class Array
{  
    int *mas, k;
    const int max;
    void Add(int);
    void Sub(int); 
 public:
    Array(const int upper = 100) : mas(nullptr), k(0), max(upper) {};     
    //...       
};
```

И не игнорируйте замечание пользователья  `pavel`